# How does one install/fix a failed numpy installation that works on python 3.4 but not in 3.5?

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, pip

I was trying to use numpy in ubuntu but it fails with error:

> Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most likely
>   you are trying to import a failed build of numpy. If you're working
>   with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all files not
>   under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

the catch is that I am using python 3.5 (that I install with the suggestions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-newer-python-versions-using-apt-get)) instead of the one that comes with the default 3.4. So I installed it as that answer suggested and then I installed numpy with:

```
pip3 install --target=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages numpy
```

so that it would install to python3.5. After that if I try to use numpy I have the above error. However if I use it on the default python 3.4 I don't have that error. I obviously tried to re-install/update/fix numpy but it didn't do anything. Specifically I did:

```
pip install --target=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages --upgrade numpy
```

is there a way to install numpy while using python 3.5 in ubuntu? How do I actually fix numpy? Why does my numpy work for 3.4 but not for 3.5?

---

the full error is:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
        from . import add_newdocs
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
        from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .type_check import *
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
        import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError:
    Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
    likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
    If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
    files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

as a caveat, I am actually doing all this by first using the cpu tensorflow docker image. So I did all this inside a docker container that has as base image the cpu tensorflow image. In particular:

```
FROM gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-py3
```

---

I also did something sort of hacky to check if at leas that would work and it didn't. What I did was append the path to my python3.4 packages in the `sys.path` for python3.5. So I went to a command line for `python3.5` and then I imported sys and went ahead to add the following string to sys.path:

```
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages')
```

it manages to import other libraries I have but it fails to import numpy however:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'
```

it seems its fine with most of the other packages except numpy. Possibly when I pip installed numpy it automatically went for the python 3.4 version or something?

---

As an extra, if one can make their answer work in a Dockerfile, that would incredibly helpful!

Comment: Seems like `pip3` here is for your python 3.4 version. You will need a separate `pip` version for the python 3.5 version. If the `pip` version for that python version is not installed, you'll have to download the `get-pip.py` script and install it using your `python3.5` installation. This should create a `pip` for `python3.5`. Just make sure you `symbolically link` this new pip to your `PATH` with a name like `pip35`.

Comment: @Abdou thanks Abdou, I also thought of that suggestion and I've been trying to do that for a few days now. If you know how to do it, I would be extremely thankful of an answer with hopefully some code or commands. Meanwhile I will keep trying.

Comment: Which part of it are you not able to complete? If you have the `get-pip.py` script downloaded, just point your `python3.5` version to it: `python3.5 get-pip.py`. This will install `pip` for that version of python. After that, you can run something like: `python3.5 -m pip install -U numpy` if you're unable to link this new `pip` to your `PATH`. Use `sudo` if you encounter permissions issues.

Comment: @Abdou I think my confusion is that I am doing this in a Dockerfile essentially. Thus, I don't really know how I would get `get-pip.py`. Like I can log in to a specific container but thats not what I want to do I want my image to have pip not just one single container. It feels that its something that should come with my python. Do I need to explicitly download that and volume the file or does it already come included somewhere?

Comment: I am not familiar with docker containers at all, to be honest. I just assumed that a container would allow the flexibility of setting up a pip instance just a normal machine would. Let's hope someone else can jump into the conversation and add something fruitful to it.

Comment: @Abdou as a side question, does any python installation come with that file or would I need to get it myself? (Right now I'm just copy pasting what I found in the web what the file is and trying to run it)

Comment: If `python3.5 -m pip` returns something like `No module named pip`, then your python3.5 did not ship with "that file"; in which case, you can google "get-pip", click on the first result and save the script as a python file (name it `get-pip.py`) onto your machine. Subsequently, you will need to run `python3.5 path_of_the_get-pip.py_script`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix and match between Python versions. Every version needs its own copy of NumPy. This is because Python does not provide a cross-version *binary* compatibility. For pure Python packages (that have no compiled code, as it is the case for NumPy), it could work in principle but the environment is hard to manage. Some distributions share the `.py` files with symlinks.

The first thing is to remove the wrong install. 
I will focus only on getting the python 3.5 install to work

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

**Warning before continuing** using the `rm` command should be done with caution, even more so as you need root privilege to operate in `/usr`.

```
rm -r numpy
```

(as root).

Then, you need pip. You can install it with a file from the pypi webpages: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/

```
cd
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

and install with

```
python3.5 get-pip.py
```

You can do this for the whole computer or just the current user (with the `--user` option). Once pip is installed,

```
python3.5 -m pip install -U numpy
```

should do.

If there is no binary package for you version of Python and pip starts to compile things and fails to do do, install the package `python3.5-dev`.

Comment: can I do `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` anywhere or does it have to be in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`? (also as a side comment, I am in a Docker container, so I can `rm` essentially without worries) (Another side comment, if you don't have `wget` do `apt-get install wget`)

Comment: You should not do the `wget` from `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`. I included a plain `cd` that will get you to the home directory before the `wget`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not? Also, you command `python3.5 -m` is really awesome! It essentially guarantees that I run the right version of pip for my python3.5 I assume. So I can't override somehow the old `pip3` and have it point to my version of python 3.5 permanently?

Comment: also why did `pip3 install --target=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages numpy` not work? How is your answer different?

Comment: (1) In the `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` you can only have python importable modules. Probably some "junk" will not break your installation but it is not a good idea to play with that. (2) as the current pip3 is installed by the system, you can see if you can use apt-get to uninstall it. Then install pip via `get-pip.py` again with python3.5 (I haven't tried this though). (3) the `pip3 ...` command will download a python3.4 package, then obey your specific request and install it in the python3.5 directory tree.