# Can one use python 3.5 in a docker container based out of the TensorFlow docker image?

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, docker, tensorflow

I was trying to use python 3.5 with my docker container. I tried:

```
gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

and

```
gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-py3
```

but it seems that both images only have python version up to 3.4. Is it possible to have as base image the docker container but also have python 3.5? Or even better, is it possible to have the base image from the official tensorflow image have python 3.5 itself?

I know its possible to pip install it in the Dockerfile as in (as shown in the [tf download page](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#pip_installation)):

```
RUN export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

however that seems that would **not** get me the **latest** tensorflow version. If one can pip install the most recent TensorFlow version why does the latest base image not a way to get the most recent TensorFlow build **and** have it in python3.5?

---

I have definitively tried installing python 3.5 as suggested by [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-newer-python-versions-using-apt-get) however, even though the installation of python 3.5 is successful, it breaks numpy in a way I can't fix (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122639/how-does-one-install-fix-a-failed-numpy-installation-that-works-on-python-3-4-bu)). Honestly, the best solution would be to just have python 3.5 automatically available on the image but for some reason its not there. I have done some research on this and it seems to install python 3.5 its a little difficult. Why is that? Is the reason python 3.5 is missing is because of tensorflow or because of ubuntu? My ideal solution would be to not have me install python 3.5 and that it comes, but it seems there might be a fundamental issue with this. What is it? Is it just because it has not been installed for tensorflow docker image and ubuntu, or am I over complicated a simple problem?

---

as another solution, I was thinking maybe to install anaconda or something and then do that, but I wanted to have tensorflow as my base image and it seems anaconda suggests to have their image as base. Since there isn't an easy way to install anaconda with apt-install I am still working to see how I can programatically install anaconda so that there can be a tensorflow image as base and then install as instructed in a Dockerfile, some version of anaconda.

---

There is now a git issue ine official tensorflow for this:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7368

---

I mentioned that one can just install TensorFlow in the DockerFile directly so here is an example docker file that worked for me:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential git libjpeg-dev
RUN apt-get install -y vim

# get wget
RUN apt-get install wget

# install python 3.5
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install python3.5

RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
RUN python3.5 get-pip.py
RUN python3.5 -m pip install -U numpy

#Install some stuff my lib needs
RUN python3.5 -m pip install -U numpy
RUN python3.5 -m pip install -U namespaces
RUN python3.5 -m pip install -U scikit-learn
RUN python3.5 -m pip install -U scipy
RUN python3.5 -m pip install -U pdb
RUN python3.5 -m pip install -U keras

#
#export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
RUN python3.5 -m pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I think the only interesting thing to note is that I installed pip directly because that package/intallation of python3.5 doesn't come with pip for it for some reason. That lead to me to install python packages to use:

```
python3.5 -m pip install
```

instead of

```
pip3
```

you can see more of those details here: [How does one install/fix a failed numpy installation that works on python 3.4 but not in 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122639/how-does-one-install-fix-a-failed-numpy-installation-that-works-on-python-3-4-bu/42124828#42124828)

Also note that I had issues installing python the "official way" (i.e. with apt-get or something like that) so I resorted to what the following question/answer suggested: https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-newer-python-versions-using-apt-get

Comment: Have you considered just starting with a base ubuntu image and then installing python3.5 and tensorflow?

Comment: @pvg yes. I suggested that at the beginning of my question. I will provide the code/Dockerfile for that in a bit at the end of my question. The issue is that that doesn't pull the most latest TensorFlow build. But it can be a short term fix.

Comment: Well, I just tried it for kicks and it took less than a minute without complaining. I think it's also not obvious (to me, at least, maybe you've figured it out) exactly what the versions in the images are. The ones you refer to are a month old. There are some there that are from half an hour ago.

Comment: Ah here. https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/images/tags/tensorflow?location=GLOBAL&project=tensorflow

You can see that 'latest' is basically the same as the latest release you get from pip. You can get even more latest which may include a python interpreter more to your liking.

Comment: @pvg interesting. It definitively did not take me under a minute to install python 3.5 on my Docker image and also successfully use it with tensorflow. Mine broke numpy for some reason. I detailed in my question how I fixed it. I would be interested in seeing how you did it. Feel free to provide it as an answer, it can still be helpful as a partial solution.

Comment: @pvg not sure I understand what your last comment means. I thought that pip got a specific version since the it clearly linked to the specific version of TensorFlow. Does the base image not get the latest working version of tensorflow? The link I provided is at least the one they recommend on the official tensorflow website it seems https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#docker_installation

Answer (score 5):

With a plain 'ubuntu' docker image from DockerHub and relying on pip to do its own dependency resolution (I wonder if *not* doing that is what causes your numpy problems) I ran:

```
apt-get install python3
apt-get install python3-pip 
pip install tensorflow
```

As far as I can tell, this gave me python3.5 with the latest tensorflow - like their docker image but with python3.5.

To me, the provided docker image is something that's intended to work 'as is' and presumably the bits and pieces provided are intended to convey the developer's higher confidence that they all work correctly together. If you need to make substantial changes it seems easier and simpler to just start from scratch.

Comment: did you do this in a Docker image? i.e. what is your base image?

Comment: @CharlieParker Yes, I did, I updated the text to reflect that.

Comment: thanks so much pvg! This is so valuable for me. I have no idea why I didn't try that. Maybe it was because my tensorflow base image only had python 3.4 or maybe I was misguided by this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-newer-python-versions-using-apt-get/881697#881697, whatever it was thanks (if you know you can tell me though). Also, what is the difference with doing your suggestion and installing tensorflow directly with a pip command `pip3 install tensorflow` and having an official tensorflow base image? I'm trying to understand which one I should be using.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no difference as they seem to keep the tf versions in pypi  (and their published wheel file) and on the image in sync. I'm guessing the docker image is the thing most closely represents the devs own environment. So if you want maximum convenience, compatibility etc, use their image. If you have other specific needs (say, you really want python3.5, etc), install tf with pip. Your tool for sorting out compatibility with your other python deps, existing code, etc is then pyenv, rather than docker . You can go on to make your own docker image with the final result.

Comment: The middle approach - start with the pre-made docker image and then try to replace one component or another with a version you want - this is perfectly reasonable in theory but in practice turns out to be a painful and unpleasant mess. So I don't think you misunderstood or were misguided by anything, you just accidentally picked the path of maximum hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Python 3 docker images are available on dockerhub nightly builds.

### CPU only

`docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-py3`

### with GPU support

`docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-gpu-py3`

---

https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags/
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3467

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to pull in a python:3.5 image and install tensorflow basing on this image, which works.

what I have in the dockerfile:

FROM python:3.5

RUN pip install tensorflow